# how to remove registry keys of recently uninstalled programs in revo uninstaller pro

Tags: windows-registry, uninstall, cleaning, revo-uninstaller

I used pc decrapifier to uninstall lots of programs because revo uninstaller takes a lot of your time just to uninstall a single program. Can I remove the registry keys and folders left behind by pc decrapifier using revo uninstaller?
Or do you know of any application that function like decrapifier and revo?

Comment: Revo takes so long **because** it can remove the keys, it has to do a lot of searching and scanning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Revo can get rid of the registry entries. Depending on which scan mode you use, it can look into more places in the registry for a deeper scan:

[image]

[**CCleaner**](http://www.ccleaner.com/) also performs registry scanning for old entries lying around.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, OP wanted to clean the Registry after the UNINSTALL OF APPLICATION has  already been made before opening Revo.
Accepted answer doesn't answer that. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible doable directly. However:

A) Re-install that target application and uninstall again, now with REVO.

OR

B) use CCleaner (or alike) to clean registry generally.